# Cannot create table in MYSQL with UNICODE and INTEGER types, ERROR: 1064

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a simple table in mysql but I am getting a syntax error.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE survey(
    id INTEGER(15)  NOT NULL,
    `name` UNICODE(65) NOT NULL,
    parentId INTEGER(15)  NOT NULL, 
    createdAt TIMESTAMP(30) NOT NULL, 
    modifiedAt TIMESTAMP (30) NOT NULL, 
    surveyUrl UNICODE(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

I have tried changing the UNICODE to STRING and placing the column names between marks with no luck. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a Datatype UNICOde and the prcision 30 for timestampo are not allowed.

You  can switch to following format, iff you need another character set and collation besides the default

More about [collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-mysql.html)

```
CREATE TABLE survey(
    id BIGINT  NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(65) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
    parentId BIGINT  NOT NULL, 
    createdAt TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL, 
    modifiedAt TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL, 
    surveyUrl varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```